# Расчет разницы между датами с учетом самих дат

Tags: android, kotlin, дата

Рассчитывается переменная содержащая разницу между датами

```kotlin
val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse)
```

Но если считать разницу, например, между 01.02.2010 и 02.02.2010 - то расчет - 1 день. А мне нужно чтобы в итоге получался результат включающий обе эти даты - то есть 2 дня.

Мне нужно просто прибавлять 1 день `.plus... .Period.of...` или есть какой-то другой способ или функция?

```kotlin
val d3: String = date3?.text.toString()
val d4: String = date4?.text.toString()
val d3parse = LocalDate.parse(d3, dateFormatInput)
val d4parse = LocalDate.parse(d4, dateFormatInput)
val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse)
outDaysText?.text = d5razn.toString()
```

Comment: прошу прощения за большой код, но AndroidStudio говорит на plusDays(1) примерно то, что мы пытаемся к Long прибавить период. Код у  меня  такой `val d3parse = LocalDate.parse(d3, dateFormatInput)`
`val d4parse = LocalDate.parse(d4, dateFormatInput)`
`val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse)`
`outDaysText?.text = d5razn.toString()`

Comment: при добавлении days ошибка `MainActivity.kt: (102, 72): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime' or '@OptIn(kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime::class)'`  И import автоматически этой библиотеки не происходит? потому что наверно она экспериментальная? На plusDay ругается красным цветом

Comment: Добавьте код в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) возвращает число (`long`) - просто прибавьте 1 без всяких дополнительных методов:

```
val d3 = "01.02.2010"
val d4 = "02.02.2010"
// val d3: String = date3?.text.toString()
// val d4: String = date4?.text.toString()
val dateFormatInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")
val d3parse = LocalDate.parse(d3, dateFormatInput)
val d4parse = LocalDate.parse(d4, dateFormatInput)
val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse) + 1
println(d5razn)  // Вывод: 2
```

Comment: спасибо, но сделал ваш первый вариант через функцию что вы сказали, просто применил её не к результату, а к дате `....between(d3parse, d4parse.plusDays(1))`. Все таки мне нужно не просто математика, а чтобы в расчет попал срок увеличенный на один день (так логичнее). Вопрос решен

Comment: @jurvrn, нет никакой разницы, хоть через метод добавлять день, хоть к результату 1 прибавлять, суть одна и та же. На мой взгляд, просто прибавление 1 читается лучше, чем вызов метода где-то в середине строки. Кстати, если решили вопрос другим способом, можете добавить свой ответ.

Comment: я понял, что технически лучше просто сложить, но все таки работаем с датой, поэтому ваш первый совет `.plusDays(1)` использовать работу с датой, а не с цифрой мне более нравится. Приложение маленькое, поэтому скорость расчета не важна ). Вы свой первый комментарий преобразуйте в ответ, я его отмечу как решение

Comment: потому что решение по вашему совету я выбрал такое - `val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse.plusDays(1))`

Comment: Ну, я в комментарии предлагал через Period делать, и добавлять день к результату between, а не ко второй дате, но в итоге через Period не получается нормально сделать. Так что это уже ваше решение)

Comment: не хочу отвлекать ваше время и внимание, но between считает только сами дни (хвостик без месяца), я выше пояснял. Может не разобрался, но и так отлично работает и не нарушает концепцию работы с датами, а не просто с числами (к исходной дате просто прибавляется один день). Помогите пожалуйста с более сложным вопросом - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309352/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0

Comment: С тем вопросом не могу помочь, потому что я не пишу под Android)